# Why doesn't my CSS font-family apply to this accented character?

Tags: css, unicode, fonts

I add the Chewy font and set it via `font-family`. But the accented character is displayed with the default font.
What am I doing wrong here?

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy';
p {
  font-family: "Chewy";
}
```

```html
<p>test blah blah</p>
<p>b&#7885;&#768;y</p>
```

Comment: What do you mean it reverts to the default font? It's keeping the same font you have specified in the css font-family: "Chewy";

Comment: When I click the button, the output doesn't use the font. You can run the code up there.

Comment: I inspect the element after pressing the button and I can see it is using font-family: "Chewy". Ensure the font has the characters you are atempting to render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most fonts do not have all the characters. For example, `ọ̀` does not exist in "Chewy". Therefore, the browser renders it using the default font.

This has nothing to do with the fact that you're using jQuery. The behaviour would be the same if the page was static.

You can try to find "groovy" looking fonts that feature this letter using [dafont](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=102&text=b%26%237885%3B%26%23768%3By&af=on). As you might notice, not many do.

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense. Is there a font type that supports all characters?

Comment: As far as I know, the most complete font in existence is the [GNU Unicode](http://czyborra.com/unifont/) font. That page also lists some of the fonts which previously attempted to support all characters (Lucinda, Everson, Bitstream,...).

Comment: @Mr.T Don't use "one font with every letter", rely on CSS fallthrough. Pick your font, then pick *another* font that can fill in the gaps and looks similar enough for your users not to notice, and come up with a list of fonts that supplement each other that way, ending in `serif` or `sans-serif` so that the browser has one final desperation fallback.